# How to print the value of a counter to a file?

Tags: counters, external-files

I'm trying to write the value of a counter to a file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\print[1]{
  \newwrite\foo
  \immediate\openout\foo=foo.txt\relax
  \immediate\write\foo{#1}
  \immediate\closeout\foo
}
\newcounter{bar}
\stepcounter{bar}
\print{hello \value{bar}}
\end{document}
```

However, the file gets this content:

```
hello \c@bar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should be `\the\value{bar}` or `\number\value{bar}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer make it an answer, I will choose it, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\value{bar}` gives only the counter. To output the value of the counter use e.g. `\the\value{bar}` or `\number\value{bar}`